# Mongo cursor with node driver

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am writing an aggregate function for mongo using the native driver, v2.1.
My code looks something like this:

```
db.collection("whatever").aggregate(...).each(function(err, doc) {
    // cursor processing
})
```

My question is: where is the cursor processing executed? On the client or on the server? 
I am assuming that it's executed on the client side (node), and if it's so, is there any way to run a cursor processing (or some other sort of data processing) on the server?

I am working with lots of gb of data, and I don't want to be transferring back and forth with mongo server.

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Little bit of internals of 'mongodb' driver's **Cursor** constructor.

When '***each***'(prototype method of Cursor constructor) method of a cursor is invoked with a callback function passed to it,

1. It fires the given query on database. Over the wire, gets the complete results set returned by the database and push into an **array** in memory at client side(node application end).
2. Then invokes the callback function given to '***each***' method by passing each element in the above **array** as argument. Of course in node style. `callback(err, doc)`

So, the point here to be noted is - once the data is received from the database, building an array and iterating through it etc. are happening at the application's end. Loading and iterating an array can be memory intensive. It is the caller's responsibility to make sure that the entire array of results set can fit the memory. Not only that, the amount of data to be transferred over the wire should also be considered.

So here are my 2 cents..

In the cases of dealing with substantial amount of data using mongodb driver,

- Better to set ''batch size' of cursor. For example, `cursor1.batchSize(100, callback)`. When batch size of the cursor is set, the cursor gets the data in batches(of 100 docs in the example above) from database, instead of trying to get the complete result set in one go. By doing it in batches, it consumes relatively less memory and/or reduced amount of data to be transferred over the wire so better performance.
- Use 'projections' in query wherever possible. Again, by using projections in right place in right way, we stop unnecessary data from being transferred to client side. So less data in size to process, less memory and better performance.
- Please be advised about doing 'sort' on cursors. Invoking 'sort' works on the complete list of documents returned by find query. If the list is big, it might slow down the query execution. When you need to do sort, check if you can use any filter in query before you sort. Not exactly a client side issue though, but our queries should be faster in execution as much as possible.

Hope this information is useful.

Thank you.